# Batchfile for Heroku and GIT not working

Tags: java, git, heroku

I am new to GIT and heroku.

```
$ sh target\bin\worker.bat
sh: targetbinworker.bat: No such file or directory.
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The Unix shell doesn't understand Windows batch files, or the backslash as path separator. Try opening up a Windows command prompt and running `target\bin\worker.bat` in it.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are using backslashes on a linux console or so.
try

sh target/bin/worker.bat

(this probably also won't work as .bat is a windows extension;
isn't there something like target/bin/worker.sh ? )

Comment: ??? post more info please, are you using cygwin or something like that? Then my comment still would apply. Or why are you calling sh on a windows machine?

Comment: and when i am using this cmd $ sh target/bin/worker.bat em getting this 

target/bin/worker.bat: line 1: @REM: command not found
target/bin/worker.bat: line 2: @REM: command not found
target/bin/worker.bat: line 3: @REM: command not found
target/bin/worker.bat: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
target/bin/worker.bat: line 4: `@REM Licensed under the Apache License, Version
2.0 (the "License");'

fablife friend actually i have installed GIT in my system(Windows plateform) and there i am using dat cmd !